# msemaphore on linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, ipc, pthreads, aix

AIX (and HPUX if anyone cares) have a nice little feature called msemaphores that make it easy to synchronize granular pieces (e.g. records) of memory-mapped files shared by multiple processes.  Is anyone aware of something comparable in linux?

To be clear, the msemaphore functions are described by following the related links [here](http://www.fkf.mpg.de/edv/docs/aix/AIX_52/usr/share/man/info/en_US/a_doc_lib/libs/basetrf1/msem_init.htm).

Answer (score 1):

[POSIX semaphores](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/semaphore.h.html) can be placed in memory shared between processes, if the second argument to `sem_init(3)`, "`pshared`", is true.  This seems to be the same as what `msem` does.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    void *shared;
    sem_t *sem;
    int counter, *data;
    pid_t pid;
    srand(time(NULL));
    shared = mmap(NULL, sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    sem_init(sem = shared, 1, 1);
    data = shared + sizeof(sem_t);
    counter = *data = 0;
    pid = fork();
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(sem);
        if (pid)
            printf("ping>%d %d\n", data[0] = rand(), data[1] = rand());
        else if (counter != data[0]) {
            printf("pong<%d", counter = data[0]);
            sleep(2);
            printf(" %d\n", data[1]);
        }
        sem_post(sem);
        if (pid) sleep(1);
    }
}
```

This is a pretty dumb test, but it works:

```
$ cc -o test -lrt test.c
$ ./test
ping>2098529942 315244699
pong<2098529942 315244699
pong<1195826161 424832009
ping>1195826161 424832009
pong<1858302907 1740879454
ping>1858302907 1740879454
ping>568318608 566229809
pong<568318608 566229809
ping>1469118213 999421338
pong<1469118213 999421338
ping>1247594672 1837310825
pong<1247594672 1837310825
ping>478016018 1861977274
pong<478016018 1861977274
ping>1022490459 935101133
pong<1022490459 935101133
...
```

Because the semaphore is shared between the two processes, the `pong`s don't get interleaved data from the `ping`s despite the `sleep`s.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using POSIX shared-memory mutexes:

```
pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
int pshared = PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, &pshared);

pthread_mutex_init(&some_shared_mmap_structure.mutex, &attr);
pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);
```

Now you can unlock and lock &some_shared_mmap_structure.mutex using ordinary pthread_mutex_lock() etc calls, from multiple processes that have it mapped.

Indeed, you can even implement the msem API in terms of this: (untested)

```
struct msemaphore {
    pthread_mutex_t mut;
};

#define MSEM_LOCKED 1
#define MSEM_UNLOCKED 0
#define MSEM_IF_NOWAIT 1

msemaphore *msem_init(msemaphore *msem_p, int initialvalue) {
    pthread_mutex_attr_t attr;
    int pshared = PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED;

    assert((unsigned long)msem_p & 7 == 0); // check alignment

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, &pshared); // might fail, you should probably check
    pthread_mutex_init(&msem_p->mut, &attr); // never fails
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

    if (initialvalue)
        pthread_mutex_lock(&attr);

    return msem_p;
}

int msem_remove(msemaphore *msem) {
    return pthread_mutex_destroy(&msem->mut) ? -1 : 0;
}

int msem_lock(msemaphore *msem, int cond) {
    int ret;
    if (cond == MSEM_IF_NOWAIT)
        ret = pthread_mutex_trylock(&msem->mut);
    else
        ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&msem->mut);

    return ret ? -1 : 0;
}

int msem_unlock(msemaphore *msem, int cond) {
    // pthreads does not allow us to directly ascertain whether there are
    // waiters. However, a unlock/trylock with no contention is -very- fast
    // using linux's pthreads implementation, so just do that instead if
    // you care.
    //
    // nb, only fails if the mutex is not initialized
    return pthread_mutex_unlock(&msem->mut) ? -1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: While it is unlikely that OP requires a semaphore (a mutex is sufficient for almost all purposes), what you've implemented is *not* a semaphore.  Hint: initialvalue can take on any nonnegative value, and zero means *locked*.

Comment: However, what the OP linked to was a mutex that only called itself a semaphore - at least, from my read of the docs in question :)

Comment: Upon a closer re-reading, it appears that you are correct.  What a misleading name!

Comment: My thinking is that it is implemented as a semaphore though we think of and use it like a mutex.  My reasons for thinking this are two fold. (1) There is no restriction that that only the process/thread that locked can unlock it, thus breaking a fundamental tenet of a mutex.  (2) The MSEM_IF_WAITERS only makes sense to me if it is keeping track of this with something like sem_getvalue() [posix] or, more likely, semop() with GETNCNT/GETZCNT options [sysv].  I guess we won't know for sure until IBM or HP opens the source.

Comment: Since the default linux pthreads implementation of mutexes doesn't do any checking to ensure the owner of the lock is the one to unlock it, that part shouldn't matter :) Anyway, I don't see anything in the documentation to talk about other numbers of waiters, but you could extend this easily enough to make a semaphore with more waiters - there's a sharable condition variable option too, after all

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, you may be able to achieve what you want with SysV shared memory; quick googling turned up [this (rather old) guide](http://fscked.org/writings/SHM/shm.html) that may be of help.

Comment: Thanks.  Msemaphores offer some convenience and simplicity that I hoped was already implemented rather than having to build it myself.